# Postgres socket connection reset

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to implement Change Data Capture in java using replication slot and Stream API of postgresql.
I am facing unusual connection breakdown problem. Here is the simple code that I am using:

```
        Properties dbConfig = new Properties();
        dbConfig.put(USER_PROPERTY, "postgres");
        dbConfig.put(PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password123");
        dbConfig.put(MIN_SERVER_VERSION_PROPERTY, "9.6");
        dbConfig.put(REPLICATION_PROPERTY, "database");
        dbConfig.put(PREFER_QUERY_MODE_PROPERTY, "simple");

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/hot";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbConfig);
        PGConnection replConnection = conn.unwrap(PGConnection.class);

        PGReplicationStream stream = replConnection.getReplicationAPI()
                .replicationStream().logical()
                .withSlotName("replication_slot3")
                .withSlotOption("include-xids", true)
                .withSlotOption("include-timestamp", "on")
                .withSlotOption("skip-empty-xacts", true)
                .withStatusInterval(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).start();

        while (true) {
            ByteBuffer msg = stream.read();
            if (msg == null) {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10L);
                continue;
            }
            int offset = msg.arrayOffset();
            byte[] source = msg.array();
            int length = source.length - offset;
            String data = new String(source, offset, length);
           * //System.out.println(data);*
            stream.setAppliedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
            stream.setFlushedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
        }
```

Here, if I comment "*System.out.println(data)*;" (which is just printing
the data in the console),
connection to the database breaks down within few second and give me this
kind of error:

```
        Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when reading from copy
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1037)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:41)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:155)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:124)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readPending(V3PGReplicationStream.java:78)
at py.com.personal.kafka.PgStreamProducer.pushToKafka(PgStreamProducer.java:40)
at py.com.personal.App.main(App.java:42)
        Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:191)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receive(PGStream.java:462)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receive(PGStream.java:446)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1170)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1035)
... 6 more
```

I was researching for some configurations and I changed a fews like these, but without results:

JVM Network settings
You can pass these two powerful timeout networking properties that can be globally applicable to all protocol handlers that uses java.net.URLConnection:

```
    conn.setNetworkTimeout(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), 60000);

    PGProperty.CONNECT_TIMEOUT.set(props, 0);
    PGProperty.SOCKET_TIMEOUT.set(props, 0);
    PGProperty.CANCEL_SIGNAL_TIMEOUT.set(props, 3600);
```

Comment: 20ms status interval seems really short to me.  Is it possible you are just flooding the connection with too much feedback?

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, the idea is provide data in near real time, for that reason the interval is set in 20 seconds. Anyway, if I set the parameter to 300 seconds I have the same error. What do you thing is the ideal value for the parameter? 
Reading other posts i found that maybe is a Garbage Collector problem, who is killing the connection.

Comment: In the docs, the author says he or she uses wal_sender_timeout / 3 which would be 20s by default.  The status is just for letting the primary know you are still connected and if the primary needs to wait on anything if there's a long-running query on the reader.  I don't see how that will help you get data in near real-time.  However, changing it also doesn't seem to help your problem.